# How to include a color scale in a barplot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, colors, bar-chart, scale

I have done a barplot:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s4YVP.png)

Here is the code:

```
# counting by month
months = np.arange(1, 13, dtype = int)
countd_months = np.zeros(12, dtype = int)
for m in months:
    countd_months[m-1] = E[E.index.month == m].count()

# setting color
values = [t.mean() for t in countd_months]

# create a normalizer
norm = Normalize(vmin=min(values), vmax=max(values))
# normalize values
norm_values = norm(values)
# choose a colormap
cmap = cm.coolwarm
# create colors
colors = cmap(norm_values)
# map values to a colorbar
mappable = cm.ScalarMappable(norm=norm, cmap=cmap)
mappable.set_array(colors)

# creating barplot
plt.figure(figsize = (16, 8))
barWidth = 0.45
plt.bar(months, countd_months, width = barWidth, color=colors)
plt.xticks(months, months_names)
for m in months:
    plt.text(x = months[m-1]-0.08, y = countd_months[m-1]+0.5, s = countd_months[m-1], size = 12)
plt.xlabel("Month")
plt.ylabel("Count")
plt.title("Number of Extreme Maximum Daily Temperatures by Month from 1980-12-31 to 2019-12-31")

plt.show()
```

The thing is that I want to set a color scale on the right side of the figure, as this example:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vOMuh.png)

Here is the last figure code:

```
data = [X_e[X_e.index.month == m] for m in range(1, 13)]

values = [t.mean() for t in data]

# create a normalizer
norm = Normalize(vmin=min(values), vmax=max(values))
# normalize values
norm_values = norm(values)
# choose a colormap
cmap = cm.coolwarm
# create colors
colors = cmap(norm_values)
# map values to a colorbar
mappable = cm.ScalarMappable(norm=norm, cmap=cmap)
mappable.set_array(colors)

fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots()
ax1.set_title('Tmax')
ba = ax1.boxplot(data, patch_artist=True)
patches = ba["boxes"]

for p, c in zip(patches, colors):
    p.set_facecolor(c)

cb = fig1.colorbar(mappable)
cb.set_label("Mean Temperature (ºC)")
```

Thus, how can I set a color scale in the barplot, like in the previous figure??

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Your question is unclear: do you mean you want each bar to be filled with a gradient? If that's the case, take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72070119/2329968

Comment: Sorry about the unclearness. Yeah, that answers my question, thanks!

Comment: Great! Go over that question and upvote the answer :)